# How Should I code The Do While loop to get the output I want to get?

Tags: c++

I code it like these to get this expected output:

It will ask first "Do you want to add data??"
Then it will take ans as a input. if ans is 1 then it will add data to the list.
otherwise it will get out of the loop.
is not working as I expected.

How Should I code The Do While loop to get the output I want to get???

```
 #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;
        
        struct list
        {
            int data;
            list *next;
        };
        
        typedef struct list node;
        
        void display(node *start)
        {
            node *temp;
            temp = start;
        
            while (temp!=NULL)
            {
                cout << temp->data << " ";
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        
        int main()
        {
        
         node *start = NULL,*temp,*prev;
         int ans;
        
         do
         {
            cout << "Do you want to add data?? " << endl;
            cin >> ans;
        
        
            if(start == NULL)
            {
                start = new node();
                cout << "Enter data " << endl;
                cin >> start->data;
                start->next = NULL;
                prev = start;
            }
        
            else
            {
                temp = new node();
                cout << "Enter data " << endl;
                cin >> temp->data;
                temp->next = NULL;
                prev->next = temp;
                prev =temp;
            }
        
         }while(ans == 1);
        
        
        
        
         display(start);
        
        
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: In the loop body, after reading the value of `ans`, your code unconditionally prompts for data - whether the user wants to add data or not.   The value of `ans` is not checked until AFTER the entire loop body is executed.    Rather than only testing if `start` is `NULL`, you ALSO need to check the value of `ans`.

Answer (score 0):

So what you would most likely want to do is use `while` instead of `do while`. `Do while` and `while` are different only in one thing, `do while` always goes in loop at least once, while `while`. So your code always goes once in loop. You type your ans, then do the loop body and after loop body you check whether ans is 1 or not. You should change it in either using `while`
Something like this

```
int main(){

    node *start = NULL, *temp, *prev;
    int ans;
    cout << "Do you want to add data?? " << endl;
    cin >> ans;
    while (ans == 1){

        if (start == NULL){
            start = new node();
            cout << "Enter data " << endl;
            cin >> start->data;
            start->next = NULL;
            prev = start;
        }

        else{
            temp = new node();
            cout << "Enter data " << endl;
            cin >> temp->data;
            temp->next = NULL;
            prev->next = temp;
            prev = temp;
        }
        cout << "Do you want to add data?? " << endl;
        cin >> ans;
    }

    display(start);

    return 0;
}
```

Or, you should check whether ans is 1 or not right after input, and break the loop if it's not 1. Something like this:

```
int main(){

    node *start = NULL, *temp, *prev;
    int ans;
    do{
        cout << "Do you want to add data?? " << endl;
        cin >> ans;
        if (ans != 1) break;
        if (start == NULL){
            start = new node();
            cout << "Enter data " << endl;
            cin >> start->data;
            start->next = NULL;
            prev = start;
        }

        else{
            temp = new node();
            cout << "Enter data " << endl;
            cin >> temp->data;
            temp->next = NULL;
            prev->next = temp;
            prev = temp;
        }
        
    }while (ans == 1);

    display(start);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `while (ans == 1)` will always be true. So the `do while` isn't the best solution here

Comment: Thank you. Yes I had code it before with the while loop as you shown here. But I wanted it to do it with a Do While Loop.

Comment: if (ans != 1) break;    Why did you use this line of code can you explain please

Comment: Well you type your ans, and you must check if he answered with 1 in order to continue loop. If he didn't type 1 you should break from loop, you should end it